# avoid cheecking arguments correctness inside the function body

Tags: typescript, language-agnostic, coding-style, refactoring, code-cleanup

I recently noticed a function written earlier in our code base which I'm certain is logically incorrect. Function is written in TypeScript and its body goes like this:

```
const getUserInitials = (user: IUser | null) => {
   if (!user) { return ""; }
   
   return (user.FirstName.charAt(0) + user.LastName.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is incorrect because this kind of function signature allows the incorrect argument to be passed by and then internally trying to fix that incorrect arg passage by returning an empty string. I think this should be rewritten with user argument holding only `IUser` type (not `IUser | null`) and that kind of argument checking should be done outside and before the function invocation so the function will always receive the correct argument.

Should that be considered as a rule of thumb when developing? I'm not talking about situations when you receive an integer and your function needs to operate only if your integer has to be let's say no more than 100. Clearly, you need to check that kind of thing inside the function because someone could pass the incorrect value which is out of your control. This seems like a legitimate concern of a function and we clearly need to check it inside to provide the correct function output.

But in the presented case there's a whole different situation - function contract says it will get you an initial of a user but in some cases, it will return just an empty string "" (which is not user initials, so it's a function contract violation in place as I see it).

I would even go further and say that function naming is incorrect and it should be called

```
getInitials(user: IUser) => {...}
```

as we clearly get user as an argument so word "user" in a function name is redundant.

1. First of all - am I correct in my understanding of the contract violation and necessity to check arguments correctness before function invocation in such cases?
2. If I am correct - are there any situations when in statically typed language checking argument correctness inside is a fine way to go (skipping cases like in my example with integer needed to be no more than 100 and cases like that, which of course have nothing to do with language type system)?
3. Is my statement about "user" in function name redundancy is correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Personally I find this more on the side of the fence of being a set of subjective questions but I will not cast the first close vote. I will however second a close vote for being subjective.

Comment: I think you should discuss it with your team mates

Comment: @GuyCoder how come is that subjective if the question discusses correct/incorrect design? Or the whole subject of a correct design is subjective you are saying?

Comment: I am not avoiding your comment, every time I write a reply it turns into an essay. The contradiction in your question is the use of what I consider two competing tags, `language-agnostic` and `typescript`.

Comment: @GuyCoder well, there's no contradiction at all. 1. language-agnostic tag - because the question is agnostic in nature and could be applied to almost every major mainstream language. 2. typescript tag - simply because the concrete example in question is made up in typescript, that's all. But the question is not about typescript specifics, that's true

Answer (score 1):

1. You are partially correct:

   a:  It never hurts to check the arguments to your function, and *design* its behavior in exceptional cases.  This is especially true in a language like Typescript, which can be called from Javascript, which is untyped. You may be right that *nobody should* call this function without a valid user,
   but that doesn't mean that *nobody will*.

   b:  If you can interpret a null argument in a meaningful way, it's often reasonable to do that and return a reasonable default.  However, I think that returning an empty string in this case is *not* reasonable.  It would be better to throw an error in this case.

   c:  If you can't return a reasonable default, then the method signature should *not* allow null arguments...  But you can *still* check for them and
   throw a more meaningful error than whatever might happen by default.  Unfortunately, many people use eslint configured in a way that will complain about such checks, and that is often the source of these `| null` additions to the method signature.
2. Static typing isn't really enough.  If your language prevents your function from being meaningfully called with arguments of the wrong type, then you never need to check the type.  Typescript is not that kind of language.
3. Absolutely not.  In typescript, the method arguments are not part of the method signature.  `getInitials(user: User)` is the same function as `getInitials(firstName: string, lastName: string)`.  If you make a function called `getInitials`, then nobody else can make another one in the same scope.  Don't presume that whatever you're doing is the one special case that deserves an unqualified name.

Comment: thanks for an extended response. 3 - could you please elaborate on that? I always thought function signature is the combination of the name and parameters by definition in any language?

Comment: "You may be right that nobody should call this function without a valid user, but that doesn't mean that nobody will." That should be a concern of a caller with incorrect args, not me as I see it. If I will design all my functions checking every possible incorrect usage and incorrect invocation this seems to be a very big overengineering and some kind of premature optimization (not in the straightforward understanding of a term of course). In the general case, we have static typing to save us from that. Will respectfully disagree with that statement (in the general case).

Comment: Re 3. In many languages that's true, but Typescript is just a type system applied to Javascript, and in Javascript, methods are looked up by name only.  So if you define a function `x` on an object, then you cannot simultaneously define a separate function`x` with different parameters on the same object or a subclass.

Comment: Re 1.  Congratulations!  If you get a call that wakes you up in the middle of the night, because something you wrote is throwing a cryptic exception, then you will be able to blame it on the person who passed you invalid arguments.  I, however, will still be asleep. :)

Comment: hah, I see where you coming from :) But the idea about all the possible checks in the general case seems a bit too extreme anyways. Thanks for the conversation and replies! appreciate it!

Comment: I'm not saying you have to check everything, but if your colleague makes a check against something that *shouldn't* happen, then you shouldn't give them a hard time about it.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Yes, you should check that a argument is valid before calling a function with that argument.

Question 3: As a rule of thumbs I'd say no. GetInitials is vague. In your example, when you're calling the function, you'd not necessarily know that it's for the initials of a user.

(This is less of a problem in object-oriented programming where you'd have User.GetInitials() so in a way User is already in the name.)

Comment: ahh. don't know about that. With that kind of logic, we should name getInitialsByUserFirstnameAndUserlastname(string: firstName, string: lastName) as (using your example) we also don't necessarily see that it's for userLastname and userFirstname. Isn't it? and GetInitials seems vague only if you somehow ignore the parameters of the function or their type. But that doesn't seem like an issue all the time we write any other functions without arguments mentioned in the name. But I see where you coming from. Anyways thanks for the answer.